# Total likes for my webpage are displaying incorrectly due to URL capitalization

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

After realizing that my website did not contain og tags and that I was missing out on some key statistical information, I quickly added the following tags to each of my articles:

- og:site_name
- og:type (article)
- og:description
- og:url
- og:title
- og:image
- fb:app_id

I also implemented the newest like button(like + ability to add a description before posting to fb). I am using the iframe version of the button.

example URL:http://www.rocksquare.com/Community/FeaturedArtists/692

**Original LIKE count: 526**

http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.rocksquare.com/Community/FeaturedArtists/692

"id": "http://www.rocksquare.com/Community/FeaturedArtists/692", "shares": 526

**Current LIKE count: 60 (from 7/13 to now)**

http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.RockSquare.com/Community/FeaturedArtists/692

"id": "http://www.RockSquare.com/Community/FeaturedArtists/692", "shares": 60

**Should be: 586 Likes**

If you look closely at the URL's you will notice that the urls are written differently. One is RockSquare.com & the other is rocksquare.com. For some reason facebook graph can tell the difference and has created two entities. One with 562 shares and one with 60. Is there anyway we can combine these two?

**Current og info**

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article"></meta>    

<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.RockSquare.com/Community/FeaturedArtists/692"></meta>

<meta property="og:title" content="Marillion: Inside the making of “Sounds That Can’t Be Made”"></meta>

<meta property="og:description" content="When a band names its new album Sounds that Can’t Be Made, you’d be forgiven for wondering what on earth it sounds like—or if it sounds like anything on Earth."></meta>

<meta property="og:image" content="http://secure.rocksquare.com/RockSquareResources/CommunityArticleFiles/cmart_img_660x305_ddd3a82a-f7df-41d9-9d54-358d065ca6b5.png"></meta>

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="268121463293096" />
```

Comment: Oh that's funny. Sorry to laugh at your pain. I think you can log this with Facebook and they will do a manual merge for you.

Comment: I think you should also file a bug report for this. Host names in URLs are to be treated case insensitive – so this is clearly erroneous behaviour, I’d say.